# Superscripts in Excel chart labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have data like this in two columns:

```
2 | 5
4 | 6
8 | 7
```

I want to plot them (scatter plot) with x={2,4,8}, y={5,6,7} but in the x-axis show 2 as 2^1, 4 as 2^2, 8 as 2^3, but not with the ^ symbol but as powers/ superscripts. I will use logarithmic scale for x. Is this possible?

I will start from 2^14 until 2^20.

I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of what you want it to look like?  I'm having trouble visualizing what is wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't natively use super/sub scripts in Excel Chart labels.  However, you can use a fairly simple trick to get Excel to do it.

1. Create your chart with your data.
2. Add three helper columns to use for your axis label points.  Use your preferred x-values and use 0 for your y-values, then add a column for your preferred label (e.g. 2^14, as 214).
3. Add the points from your helper columns to your chart.
4. Format the new series (which should be a series of points along the x-axis) to no point (or a cross, if you'd prefer a "tick" on the axis).
5. Now, you'll need to download  [Rob Bovey's XY Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) and install it as an Excel add-in. If you want to break out of Excel's basic formatting to do interesting Charts, this is a must-have (or you could write your own version in VBA).
6. Using Chart Labeler, select your helper series and assign the label column as your series' labels, with a location = Bottom.
7. Finally, select the superscript portion of each label and format your font for superscript.  This has to be done individually for each label. Also, if you update the values, you'll have to reformat.

[image: superscript labels]

Comment: +1 and accepted. Seems too hard for me. I should learn how to use R for such tasks

Comment: Thanks. I've done some work in R (and with R Commander it can interface with Excel), and in my opinion learning the above system is still much easier.  If you'd like more detailed directions, just let me know and I can expand any unclear parts of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could create text boxes containing the axis labels just as you want them to appear.

While typing into a text box, highlight the text you want to appear superscript and press the plus sign key while holding CTRL + ALT. Click and grab the green dot on the text box to rotate it.

[image]